# Нужно ли ставить здесь две запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Ты знал(,) что это такое(,) в 10 классе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно, они отделяют придаточное предложение от главного. Однако я бы поменяла порядок слов. **Ты знал в десятом классе, что это такое?** Тогда смысл будет более ясно выражен. Иначе можно запутаться и подумать, что спрашивают о том, знал ли человек, каково это - учиться/быть в 10 классе.